# Excel office API : Invoke a function from taskpane

Tags: office-js, custom-functions-excel

I'm new to develop excel add-in and as part of this need to invoke a excel function. I've went through several docs but didn't find in detail information.

Following is my sample code :

```
async function run() {
  try {
    await Excel.run(async context => {
    // Code for invoking a excel function
    await context.sync();
});
} catch (error) {
console.error(error);
}
}
```

Please provide a useful guide or let me know how to invoke a custom function from a task pane.

Comment: Hi @madireddy,

Are you trying to call a built-in function, like ABS or FLOOR, from your add-in? If so, please check out [Call built-in Excel worksheet functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-worksheet-functions).

If you're looking to create a custom function (something end-users can add to cells in Excel), please read [Create custom functions in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-overview]).

Comment: Hi Alexander, I've created set of custom functions and able to invoke the functions in the worksheet directly. Now I'm designing the task pane which shown all the custom functions and user can select the function and use the provided "insert" button to invoke function directly in the active cell.  I've used https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-overview as a reference.  The provided second link is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the guide [office-js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/overview/excel-add-ins-reference-overview) which helped me to solve my problem. Thanks for all who ever responded.